# How to specify and use a cert file during a docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

My company just updated our security and now we need to add the use of a custom cert file. My local docker builds are now failing to download packages during the build. To fix this I need to use a cert file in the docker build.

If I try to build the image with the Dockerfile at the end of this post I get the following error indicating the permission is denied because it needs the cert -

```
=> ERROR [4/4] RUN apk update && apk upgrade                                                                                                            0.3s
------                                                                                                                                                        
 > [4/4] RUN apk update && apk upgrade:                                                                                                                       
#8 0.194 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz                                                                        
#8 0.232 140008555400008:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1913:
#8 0.233 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: Permission denied
#8 0.233 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: No such file or directory
#8 0.233 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#8 0.273 140008555400008:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1913:
#8 0.273 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: Permission denied
#8 0.273 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: No such file or directory
#8 0.273 2 errors; 14 distinct packages available
```

If I comment out the `RUN apk update && apk upgrade`, it will build. I shell into the container, manually run `export SSL_CERT_FILE=~/trusted-certs.pem`, then manually run `apk update && apk upgrade` it will perform the apk install fine.

I have tried using ENV and ARG also with no luck.

If I update the apk command in the Dockerfile like this `RUN SSL_CERT_FILE=~/biw-trusted-certs.pem apk update && SSL_CERT_FILE=~/biw-trusted-certs.pem apk upgrade` it will work during the build but this will be tedious to add to all the apk commands.

I do need this to work in Alpine linux.

**My Dockerfile -**

```
FROM alpine:3.14.1

COPY trusted-certs.pem ~/trusted-certs.pem

#ARG SSL_CERT_FILE=~/trusted-certs.pem
#ENV SSL_CERT_FILE=~/trusted-certs.pem
RUN export SSL_CERT_FILE=~/trusted-certs.pem

RUN apk update && apk upgrade
```

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured it out.

All works with this -

```
FROM alpine:3.14.1

COPY trusted-certs.pem /root/trusted-certs.pem
RUN SSL_CERT_FILE=~/trusted-certs.pem apk add ca-certificates
RUN update-ca-certificates
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add curl
RUN curl https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip -o awscliv2.zip
```

Even cleaner :

```
FROM alpine

COPY ./trusted-certs.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN cat /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/trusted-certs.pem >> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache jq
RUN apk add curl
RUN curl https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip -o awscliv2.zip
```